# Dividing a filtered subcolumn with grand total

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hey guys is there a more elegant solution to divide one column that is not a value field with a grand total. Below is a picture of what I have:

[image]

I want to have another column at the end of the pivot that will have cells from "Same" column divided by cells from Grand Total.

Here is what I tried:

- Simply put =D5/E5 (D is column Same, E is column Grand Total) and autofill it down. This solution is messy because pivot will change its length
- Tried with getpivotadata without success. All cells in calculated field end up having the same value.
- Adding a calculated field. Problem  with this is that the column SAME is not a value field offered, its just one of the values within grouping value field.
- Adding another grouping into values of pivot, renaming it % and changing it to be a percentage of parent column. Problems here are 1-% of SAME isnt at the end of the pivot, 2- I get % of other columns belonging to grouping column which I dont want. 3- excel adds more text that i cant remove (count of grouping in each column) , 4- I am forced to hide excess columns and make whoever will be using the files prone to mistakes while doing vlookups and VBA. 
  I am using excel 2010. 
  Is there an easier way to solve this that keeps eluding me? Thanks

Comment: for a quick an easy solution you could just warp `=D5/E5` in `IFERROR` like so: `=IFERROR(D5/E5,"")`. Then when the pivot changes it length, it will atleast not show the `#DIV/0`-Error

Comment: Hi Marco, 
Thats not the point. I dont mind having DIVs as the Vlookup will simply not pick those entries up. problem with that solution is that I will be forced to have a huuuuuuge line of formulas in already heavy excel spreadsheet to make sure each row has a formula no matter how big the pivot ends up being. I thought that there is a way to have a solution column that will always be as big as the pivot in length.